# Check the sufficiency for my proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

Question is :

Let $n\in\mathbf{Z}$ s.t. $7\mid(n^3+1)$
But 7 does not divide $(n^2-2n-3)$
Prove that $7\mid(4n+1)$

I get $7$ does not divide $(n+1),$ $(n+4)$ and $7\mid(n^2-n+1)$ from the first two lines
And I try to convert the question to: if $7\mid(n^2-n+1)$, prove that $7 \mid (4n+1)$.
Then I try to prove the contrapositive statement false, assuming that $4n+1$ does not equal $7m,$

Then $n^2-n+1$ does not equal $7\cdot [(7m^2-6m+3)/16],$ I wonder if it's sufficient to prove?

Comment: Pleas always include a tag that indicates the subject matter. Also, please use MathJax to format all the mathematics in your post.

Answer (score 0):

For a “slick” solution (this is likely how the author of the question came up with it, but you aren’t expected to reverse engineer it), you can rewrite the condition as $7 \mid n^3 + 8$, which factors into $(n+2)(n^2-2n+4)$.

The second factor is congruent mod $7$ to $n^2-2n-3$, so if $7$ doesn’t divide that factor then (since $7$ is prime), it must divide the other factor $n+2$.  If so, then it also divides $4(n+2) = 4n+8,$ which is congruent to $4n+1$ mod $7$.

Comment: Really thank you for the help, the solution is amazing!